# Can't open select2 after init

Tags: jquery-select2

On `select2 4.0.2`, right after I init select2, I try to do :

```
$(myelement).select2("open")
```

and I have this error :

> The select2('open') method was called on an element that is not using Select2

Comment: What does your initialization code look like and what is `myelement`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working example. Are you sure to use same element use for initialization of Select2?

```js
$("#myField").select2();
$("#myField").select2("open");
```

```css
.select2 {
  width:50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select2" id="myField" name="myField" autocomplete="off">
</select>
```